# How to test JSP files?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a web application using Spring MVC and I am developing JSP pages for the user interface. I am not writing any logic in JSP pages. But just that I am using the JSP's "forEach" tag in order to loop over the list which is the model object set from the Controller and display the records in a table form on the user interface. All the logic is working fine.

I want to test the model object i am using on the JSP page. That is I want to test the JSP page in order to check whether the number of rows in the table are displayed correctly with the size of the list.

For example: If the list size is one i want to test whether the table has one row or not. If the list size is two whether the table has two rows or not and if the list size is zero i want to check whether the table has zero rows or not.

I have used http unit and html unit in order to test my JSP pages. These frameworks are working fine for http unit web sites but its working for my application (I am running my application on Apache Tomcat 8.0). I am seeing this is below error when I am trying to run http unit in order to test the page of my application:

failed: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "createElement" of undefined (httpunit#1325)

So is there any way I could test my JSP pages either by solving this error or by some other framework which works for the application hosted on the Tomcat server. I am ready to try any thing that is there in order to test the JSP pages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just create a dynamic java based web project?

Comment: Test your controller and model with MockMvc. I've never tested a view but it looks like you could extend AbstractViewRenderTest like shown in this example https://www.stuartgunter.org/posts/unit-testing-views-spring-mvc/

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte The project is a dynamic web project. But what makes the difference with the kind of the project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573408/476716

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: Test JSP Output in JUnit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573408/spring-test-jsp-output-in-junit-test)